# Elasticsearch scripting - convert unix timestamp to "YYYYMM"

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-2.0

I am using Elasticsearch 2.4 and I have a Groovy script. I have a field in my document say `doc['created_unix_timestamp']` which is type `integer` and it holds Unix timestamp. In a search query's script, I am trying to get `YYYYMM` from that value.

For example, if `doc['created_unix_timestamp']` is `1522703848`, then in the scripting during a calculation, I want to convert it to as `201804` where first 4 digits are Year and last two are month (with padded 0, if required)

I tried:

```
Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat('YYYYMM').format(new Date(doc['created_unix_timestamp'])))
```

But it throws "compilation error" `"TransportError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to compile groovy script')"` . Any idea how to get it work or what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Maybe you are missing import to `SimpleDateFormat`? Have you tried more Groovy-like approach - `(new Date(doc.created_unix_timestamp).format('yyyyMM')).toInteger()` ?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak Groovy like suggestion doesn't throw any compilation error :) but it gives the wrong result. e.g. `return (new Date(1522703848).format('yyyyMM')).toInteger()` return `197001` that is January 1970, while it shoudl have been `201804`

Comment: @SzymonStepniak while debugging, I found `new Date(1522703848).format('yyyyMM')` this equates to `None`

Comment: @SzymonStepniak I got it worked. Since `Date` constructor is expecting  in milliseconds https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29 , so I changed the line to `(new Date(1522705958L*1000).format('yyyyMM')).toInteger()` and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A couple recommendations.

1. Reindex and make `created_unix_timestamp` a true date in elasticsearch.  This will make all kinds of new querying possible (date range for example).  This would be ideal.
2. If you can't reindex, then pull it back as an int from ES and then convert it to whatever you want client side, I wouldn't recommend pushing that work to the ES cluster.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion of Szymon Stepniak in above comment, I solved this issue by

```
(new Date(1522705958L*1000).format('yyyyMM')).toInteger()
```

Thanks and credit goes to Szymon Stepniak